# how to update 1 property in 1 object in an BehaviorSubject and let all observers know

Tags: rxjs

If I have a `BehaviorSubject` which is a list of objects

```
files$: BehaviorSubject<FileToUpload[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

How can I update 1 property in 1 object of the list and notify all observers without doing something like:

```
files$.next([files.map(f => {
  if(f === condition) {
    f.changed = true;
  }
  return f
})]);
```

Is there a terser way of doing this?